# What does "+!!" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following codes

```
var value = 0;
for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    value += +!!arguments[i];
}
```

What does `+!!` really do here? Is it one good programming style in JavaScript?

Comment: Not very readable to the untrained eye. One can easily do better, like using a ternary operator

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript.

Comment: Actually, the `+` is not needed here, since the addition will coerce the boolean to a number anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not one operator, it's three: `+` and then `!` twice.

What that does is apply `!` to `arguments[i]`, which turns *truthy* values `false` or *falsy* values to `true`, and then applies `!` to make `false` => `true` and vice-versa, and then applies the unary `+` to convert the result to a number (`true` => `1`, `false` => `0`).

A *falsy* value is any value that coerces to `false`. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`. A *truthy* value is any other value.

So the net result is to add the count of truthy values in `arguments` to `value`.

> Is it one good programming style in JavaScript?

Using `!!` to turn something truthy into `true` and something falsy into `false` is completely normal practice. Using the unary `+` to convert something to a number is also completely normal practice.

Comment: Well, for consistency I suggest you start using "truey" then.

Comment: @torazaburo: "truthy" and "falsy" are no more similar than "truthy" and "falsey". It would have to be "truy" and "falsy" or "truey" and "falsey" or "truthy" and "falsehoody". English is anarchic.

Answer (score 7):

`!!arguments[i]` is a common idiom, which applies the logical negation twice, to convert the expression `arguments[i]` to a real boolean value.

For example,

```
console.log(!!{});
// true
```

Why we need two logical negations here? Because, it doesn't change the parity of the data. For example,

if the data was originally [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then `!Truthy` will become `false` and then inverting it again `!false`, you will get `true`.

if the data was originally [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), then `!Falsy` will become `true` and then inverting it again `!true`, you will get `false`.

---

The `+` operator at the beginning of `+!!arguments[i]` is to make sure to get a Number value out of the boolean, (as `!!arguments[i]` is guaranteed to give a boolean).

In JavaScript, when `true` is converted to a number you will get `1`, and `0` for `false`.

```
console.log(+true);
// 1
console.log(+false);
// 0
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have refered to `!!` as an idiomatic unit, well said.

Comment: Perhaps you could opine on the second question, which is "Is it one good programming style in JavaScript?".

Answer (score 0):

Often `!!` is used to convert variable to boolean type, and `+` to number.
In this example it is first converted to boolean then to number in this case to 1 or 0.
Variable `value` contains number of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Truthy) parameters passed to function.